# Strange Files in AppData Roaming (IS IT A VIRUS?)

Tags: malware, windows, virus

I am not familiar with programming or something, but I have found a strange file in AppData>Roaming called
vtivhwvr.exe Is it a virus??
I am also can't delete it and having strange CPU activity, it is loads to 5-7% in idle (later it was 1-2% in idle)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like one. What do you mean by _"I can't delete it"_?

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion that looks like a randomly generated .exe name so a general lookup about the executable is useless. I would recommend that you use malewarebytes on a trial just to do an initial scan and pick up what signature it is and give that pc a good clean. Chances are that the exe has run and there is a whole bunch of things injected everywhere already, so deleting is useless.

Sorry wanted to comment.

Comment: As you note, this is not an "Answer" as such but a comment. I know, you can't comment without more reputation points.

Comment: Was just trying to help.

Comment: This is kinda the reason I shy away from platforms like this. Everybody seems to be so self righteous about how the platform works and not about helping a person out. All I am trying to do is give back to a community in any way I can.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't know exactly what this file is really is because it can be generated by a service that you installed, so, i think the easy way to be sure is to upload it to Virustotal.com, any.run or hybrid-analysis.com, virus total will match the hash with different AV and the other two will run it into a sandbox environment and based on its behavior they will give you a resolution and you can see what this file is really does in your system.
If you enabled the Windows logs security, I can help you and analyse them.